# How can i assign these "var" results to different variables?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, var

These are my results:

[image]

Hey everyone.

I want these results to be assigned on different variable.

For example;

```
stringone = "Etiler";
stringtwo = "Kağıthane";
stringthree = "Şişli";
```

Comment: What you are asking is not clear at all

Comment: @maccettura: Judging by the screenshot the questioner is looping through a 1 column database result set and wants to assign the value of each row to different independently named variables.

Comment: Okay then let me put it this way. Look at the picture first. I am pulling some data from database that returns many results into one "var" variable. But i need to assign these result, which returns from database, to string variables. So i need to each results to its own variable. Did i make it clear?

Comment: What type is `var` (never use var unless the type can be inferred from your code).  Is the count of results static (i.e will it always return `x` results)?

Comment: @RifKohen You can't really do that... that's what collections are for. You can  put them in an array and use indexing. It would look like this: `var myArray = db.Servis.ToArray();` then `var stringOne = myArray[0]`.

Comment: no its not static. it returns whatever is in the database. sometimes 1 sometimes 10 results return.

Comment: how can i add DISTINCT to "var result = db.servis.Where(s => ...).ToList();"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

C# <s>is strongly typed</s> variables must be defined at compile time, so you can not create variables dynamically at runtime. 
However, you can use a collection to hold your results.

Using a list:

```
var result = db.servis.Where(s => ...).ToList();
// access first element:
var first = result.ElementAt(0);
```

Using an array:

```
var result = db.servis.Where(s => ...).ToArray();
// access first element:
var first = result[0]; // here "0" is the array index
```

Using a dictionary:

```
var result = db.servis.Where(s => ...)
    .Select((item, index) => new {index, item})
    .ToDictionary(x => "string" + (x.index + 1), x => x.item);
// access first element:
var first = result["string1"]; // here "string1" is the key of the key value pair
```

Comment: The only reason I can think of was your reasoning. It is not impossible because C# is strongly typed, it is impossible because you can't create variables at runtime. (Just to clarify I wasn't the person who downvoted you)

Comment: how can i add DISTINCT to "var result = db.servis.Where(s => ...).ToList();"

Comment: You can use the LINQ `Distinct()`: `var result = db.servis.Where(s => ...).Distinct().ToList();`. In this case it will use the default [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx), you can also pass a custom one.